# Css overflow-y scroll bar going outside of div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In dropdown menu overflow scroll bar going outside of list. How i can fix this issue.
This is my code

```
li.flyout-mega > a:hover
{
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 80vh;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  overflow: visible;}
```

[image]

Comment: If you really need a scroll, inspect it in the Chrome developer tool and play around with it. Change some values and see what works. I am sure you will find a solution. Or you can put snippet code here so we can take a better look. Could be related with links or something. Something is pushing it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have fixed the issue, actually scrollbar background color was transparent and now i have just added background color now it's working fine thanks.

```
li.flyout-mega > a:hover
 {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 80vh;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  overflow: visible;
  scrollbar-color: #d1172e #fff;
  scrollbar-width: thin; 
  }
```